# Cannot code auto increment id in SQLite Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have just created a new column, Id in DB Browser sqlite. I am not sure how am I suppose to code this portion in App.py. Should I use a id = request.form['id]?

**App.py**

```
@app.route('/addrec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        id = 
        use = session['user'].get("name")
        ema = session['user'].get("preferred_username")
        type = request.form['type']
        uploadre = request.form['uploadre']
        amt = request.form['amt']
        description = request.form['description']

        if request.form.get("price"):
            price_checked = "Yes"
        else:
            price_checked = "No"

    conn = sql.connect(db_path)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(
        "INSERT INTO SubmitClaim VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (id, use,ema, type, uploadre, amt,price_checked, description))
    conn.commit()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM  SubmitClaim")
    print(c.fetchall())
    conn.close()

    return render_template('base.html', user=session["user"], version=msal.__version__)
```

**This is my table in DB Browswer Sqlite**

```
CREATE TABLE "SubmitClaim" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "Name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Email" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "ClaimType" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "UploadReceipt" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "ClaimAmount"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "checkbox"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "ClaimDescription"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
)
```

Comment: Specifiy `id` as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and it will be an auto-incrementing identity column - no need to set it in the `INSERT` statement.

See: 

https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/

Comment: When I add in the id column in DB browser and I dont define it...I will get this error sqlite3.OperationalError: table SubmitClaim has 8 columns but 7 values were supplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you set up an integer primary key column in sqlite and then insert and select from it:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
conn.execute('''
CREATE TABLE SubmitClaim (
    Id                INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name              NVARCHAR NOT NULL,
    Email             NVARCHAR NOT NULL,
    ClaimType         NVARCHAR NOT NULL,
    UploadReceipt     NVARCHAR NOT NULL,
    ClaimAmount       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Checkbox          NVARCHAR NOT NULL,
    ClaimDescription  NVARCHAR NOT NULL
)
''')
conn.commit()

conn.execute("INSERT INTO SubmitClaim (Name, Email, ClaimType, UploadReceipt, ClaimAmount, Checkbox, ClaimDescription) VALUES ('Foo Bar', 'foo@bar.com', 'A', 'Blah', 10, 'Checked', 'Description goes here')")
conn.commit()

cursor = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM SubmitClaim')

for row in cursor:
  print(row)
```

And here's a colab notebook demonstration: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OhV9lWSBxLpOv45bNKmtRx9H0j6BZ-S3?usp=sharing

So your code sample above becomes:

```
@app.route('/addrec', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        use = session['user'].get("name")
        ema = session['user'].get("preferred_username")
        type = request.form['type']
        uploadre = request.form['uploadre']
        amt = request.form['amt']
        description = request.form['description']

        if request.form.get("price"):
            price_checked = "Yes"
        else:
            price_checked = "No"

        conn = sql.connect(db_path)
        conn.execute('''
            INSERT INTO SubmitClaim 
                (Name, Email, ClaimType, UploadReceipt, ClaimAmount, Checkbox, ClaimDescription) 
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', 
            (use, ema, type, uploadre, amt, price_checked, description))
        conn.commit()

        c = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM  SubmitClaim")
        print(c.fetchall())
        conn.close()

    return render_template('base.html', user=session["user"], version=msal.__version__)
```

Comment: In my Db Browser, The id is auto incremented but I cant seem to submit anymore forms. I am getting this error:
sqlite3.OperationalError: table SubmitClaim has 8 columns but 7 values were supplied

Comment: Use the table definition I supplied and the `INSERT` statement also - yours does not specify the columns to insert into, only the values, which is probably the cause of your error

Comment: I tried using yours but I have already created the table *Submit Claim*. If user wishes to submit a form everytime, I have to create a new table everytime?

Comment: No, you do not need to create a new table every time - this would of course destroy the existing data.

But assuming you don't have any data in there that you care about, I would suggest to drop and recreate the table using the above definition, as you did not specify your id column as `NOT NULL` 

As said, I think your error comes from the fact that your `INSERT` statement needs to supply a list of columns, as in my example.

Comment: Yes I understand. However, user have to submit a form and data is pass to DB Browser, I dont want to hardcode the values as shown in your answer. How do i drop and recreate the table *Submit Claim* ? I have added a new column, ID and they are auto incremented, not null and primary key. 
When I try to submit the form, I am face with an error again.

Comment: I mean that as in the example, you should add the list of columns to your insert statement, thus: `conn.execute("INSERT INTO SubmitClaim (Name, Email, ClaimType, UploadReceipt, ClaimAmount, Checkbox, ClaimDescription) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (name, email, claim_type, upload_receipt, claim_amount, checkbox, description))`

Comment: I corrected your initial code sample and added to answer..

Comment: Hi ultra909, I have solve by using your code, thanks so much!